# PyCharm no reconoce módulos instalados

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pycharm

Tengo el siguiente problema: tengo Python3 instalado en mi sistema(Ubuntu 18.04) y tengo instalado el módulo numpy, lo cual puedo comprobar así:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> print(numpy.__version__)
1.17.4
>>>
```

Sin embargo, cuando creo un proyecto nuevo en PyCharm, no me reconoce el módulo numpy como instalado:

```
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Cuando PyCharm crea el proyecto, crea una carpeta *venv* y yo estoy casi seguro que el problema esta ahí, en algún entorno virtual que crea por defecto, pero no sé como solucionarlo, y no quiero tener que instalar en ese entorno los módulos que tengo ya instalados. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ya encontré la solución. La dejo aquí por si alguien tiene la misma duda. Lo que se debe hacer es desplegar la pestaña *Project Interpreter* cuando se crea un nuevo proyecto y marcar *Existing Interpreter* en lugar de *New Enviroment*, que viene marcado por defecto. Aqui les muestro una imagen
[image: Creando un nuevo proyecto]

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta :), es triste que un ide tan bueno como pycharm tenga esas carencias, en mi caso, el error que tenia era que no reonocio pygame y pyglet

Comment: sí, de hecho debes elegir un enviroment (basicamente un interprete) para cada proyecto que crees